# Flutter Riverpod infinite loading while using a controller that fetches data

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, state, riverpod

I'm struggling with understanding the issue that I end up in. My FutureProvider can't depend on a Controller that has asynchronous added data. I would love to understand the mechanics that lead to that behavior and fix this problem.

I've prepared some code snippets showing you the majority of the data that is needed to understand this problem.

The application should show a screen that has list of profiles. I use for it a **fetchProfileListProvider** **FutureProvider**.

```
imports ...

class ProfileRepositoryImpl implements ProfileRepository {
  final ProfileDataSource dataSource;

  ProfileRepositoryImpl({
    required this.dataSource,
  });

  ...

  @override
  Future<List<Profile>> fetchProfileList() async {
    return await dataSource.fetchProfileList();
  }

  ...
}

final profileRepositoryProvider = Provider<ProfileRepository>((ref) {
  final profileDataSource = ref.watch(profileDataSourceProvider);
  return ProfileRepositoryImpl(dataSource: profileDataSource);
});

...

final fetchProfileListProvider = FutureProvider<List<Profile>>((ref) async {
  // This watch is taking care of the logout status change.
  ref.watch(authControllerProvider);

  // ==== This watch is creating the problem (no error, but problem)
  ref.watch(filtersControllerProvider);
  // ==== Without it the code works

  final profileRepository = ref.watch(profileRepositoryProvider);
  return await profileRepository.fetchProfileList();
});
```

Now I want you to show the **filterControllerProvider** implementation.

```
imports...

class FiltersController extends StateNotifier<FiltersState> {
  final FiltersRepository filtersRepository;

  FiltersController({required this.filtersRepository})
      : super(const FiltersState()) {

    // After commenting this line the problem disappears
    // But I need those data to manipulate in the state
    fetchFilters();
  }

  Future<void> fetchFilters() async {
    state = state.copyWith(filters: const AsyncValue.loading());
    state = state.copyWith(filters: const AsyncValue.data(null));
    state = state.copyWith(
        filters:
            await AsyncValue.guard(() => filtersRepository.fetchFilters()));
  }

  Future<void> _updateFilters(Filter filters) async {
    ... Implementation details
  }

  Future<void> updateGender(List<Gender> genders) async {
    ... Implementation details
  }

  Future<void> updateLocationRange(double locationRange) async {
    ... Implementation details
  }

  Future<void> updateAgeRange(List<int> ageRange) async {
    ... Implementation details
  }
}

final filtersControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<FiltersController, FiltersState>((ref) {
  final filtersRepository = ref.watch(filterRepositoryProvider);
  return FiltersController(filtersRepository: filtersRepository);
});
```

Now the **FilterState**, nothing special (yes I need the loading when doing updates).

```
imports...

class FiltersState extends Equatable {
  final AsyncValue<Filter?> filters;
  final AsyncValue<bool> loading;

  const FiltersState({
    this.filters = const AsyncValue.data(null),
    this.loading = const AsyncValue.data(false),
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [filters, loading];

  FiltersState copyWith({
    AsyncValue<Filter?>? filters,
    AsyncValue<bool>? loading,
  }) {
    return FiltersState(
      filters: filters ?? this.filters,
      loading: loading ?? this.loading,
    );
  }
}
```

And now the **FilterRepositoryProvider**

```
imports...

class FiltersRepositoryImpl extends FiltersRepository {
  final FiltersDataSource dataSource;

  FiltersRepositoryImpl({required this.dataSource});

  @override
  Future<Filter> fetchFilters() async {
    return await dataSource.fetchFilters();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateFilters(Filter filter) async {
    ... Implementation details
  }

  @override
  Future<void> createFilters(PreFilter preFilter) async {
    ... Implementation details
  }
}

final filterRepositoryProvider = Provider<FiltersRepository>((ref) {
  final dataSource = ref.watch(filtersDataSourceProvider);
  return FiltersRepositoryImpl(dataSource: dataSource);
});
```

Now the app behavior:
**How it should work** => We should get a screen with the list of profiles that changes when I change the filters.

**How it is working now** => Infinite loading indicator.
[image: This is the proper way the screen should look like. And if we change the filters above it should refetch new data.][image: This is the way it is now. The screen has an infinite loading.]

I tried to rewrite this into using a FutureProvider for fetching the filters repository and pass the data into the controller as arguments but the problem still appears.

Every time I am dependent on a controller that need to get async data it doesn't work.

Could you please help me out understand the issue?